# count rows from dependant queries

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have something like this

```
With q as ( some valid query),
     r as (some other valid query)
```

I'd like the result to be the number of rows in `q` and `r`

so I need to do `select(*) from q` and `select(*) from r`

How can I do this in t-sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
With q as ( some valid query),
     r as (some other valid query)
select COUNT(*) as total from q
UNION ALL
select COUNT(*) as total from r
```

Result

```
total
20054
2548
```

If you want to put it as columns, then you can very similar what @gbejic suggested:

```
With q as ( some valid query),
     r as (some other valid query)
select (SELECT COUNT(*) from q) as q, (SELECT COUNT(*) from r) as r
```

Comment: you count first table and add count another table. You will get 2 rows of count

Comment: is there a way to make it as named columns?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
(select COUNT(*) from q) + (select COUNT(*) from r)
```